Як правильно сказати українською "заниматься гимнастикой?
Добрий день,
Скажуть, будь ласка, як правильно сказати українською заниматься гимнастикой?
Перше, що спадає на думку -- це займатися гімнатикою, проте мовознавці кажуть, що в українській займатися означає загорятися.
Я б хотів знати, яке українське слово використали б українці, які не мали нікого впливу російської.

This question is similar to: Яке головне значення дієслова "займатися"? І чи можна займатися наукою, політикою, здоров'ям, коханням тощо?.

Спасибі за посилання, проте жодна відповідь за ним не відповідає на моє запитання.

Я не кажу, що займатися гімнастикою це неправильно, але ось ще як можна

Занятие гимнастикой - гімнастикува́ння.
Упражняться в гимнастике - гімнастикува́тися.
Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)

І тоді

Заниматься гимнастикой - гімнастикувати.


Якось не милозвучно

@RomanMikhol хіба з незвички. У нас є подібні слова: жебракувати, гендлювати. Я сам до цього слова дійшов розмірковуючи над питанням і лише потім підтвердив здогад через словник.

Не маю заперечень до такого способу словотворення. Пан - панує, жебрак - жебракує, воїн - воює, консультант - консультує. Та не певен, що проста форма дієслова буде притаманна для всіх іменників. Спробуємо утворити її від: Президент, футболіст, суддя, аспірант та ін. Можливо, існують якісь критерії або умови, виконання яких дозволяє створювати просту дієслівну форму від іменників?

@RomanMikhol Президентувати, футболювати, суддіювати, аспірантувати.

Я так би й сказала займатися гімнастикою.
Гімнастикува́тися дійсно незвично (але я не мовознавець).
Тепер цікаво, чи буде правильним казати тренуватися гімнастикою? Чи тренуватися в гімнастиці?

Якщо ви хочете отримати відповідь, то вам треба це оформити як нове запитання, бо зараз це у вас частина відповіді.

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review
